# xUnit + Unquote testing: report the first item where lists differ enough

Tags: unit-testing, f#, xunit, numeric, f#-unquote

I am writing a numerical differential equation solver. In my tests, I need to compare the list of `actual` values, produced by my code, and a list of `expected` values computed from the analytical solution, and detect if and when the two lists deviate from each other by a value greater than `tolerance`.

Here is my code up to now:

```
module Tests

open System
open Xunit
open Swensen.Unquote

open NumericalIntegrator.Stepping

let isWithinToleranceOf expectedFunc tolerance actual =
    let helper (x, y) =
            expectedFunc x - tolerance <! y
            expectedFunc x + tolerance >! y
            
    actual
    |> List.map helper
    |> ignore

// ... other tests...

[<Fact>]
let ``y' = y`` () =
    let theDiffEq (x, y) = y
    let delta = 5e-4
    let initialConditions = (0.0, 1.0)
    let expectedFunc x = Math.Exp x
    let numSteps = 200u
    let tolerance = 1e-5

    let actualResult = stepMany numSteps theDiffEq delta initialConditions

    actualResult
    |> isWithinToleranceOf expectedFunc tolerance
```

This code gives me this test failed message:

```
Un totale di 1 file di test corrisponde al criterio specificato.
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.92]     Tests.y' = y [FAIL]
  X Tests.y' = y [202ms]
  Messaggio di errore:
   

1.039760484 < 1.039760349
false

Expected: True
Actual:   False
  Analisi dello stack:
// [omitted]

L'esecuzione dei test non è riuscita.
```

I would like to display the following information:

- The first index for which `actual` is not within tolerance of `expected`
- The values of `expected` and `actual` at this index
- The value of `tolerance`

I know it should be possible to catch and rethrow the exception generated by xUnit, but I only managed to do so very poorly:

```
let isWithinToleranceOf expectedFunc tolerance actual =
    let helper (x, y) =
            expectedFunc x - tolerance <! y
            expectedFunc x + tolerance >! y
    
    try
        actual
        |> List.map helper
        |> ignore
    with
    | e ->  printfn "\n\nMy info here\n\n"
            raise e
```

What should I do?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

- use a fucntion which returns bool or Result instead of throwing an
  exception
- use try/catch within `helper`, do not surround the entire
  iteration use `mapi` instead of `map`
- to get the current index within
  iteration
- use `failwith` to throw own exception or `reraise()` as an equivalent of `throw;` in C#; or raise some Xunit exception

where XunitException is handled special in the test explorers and IDEs. You can use it to throw an assertion error, or inherit from it to define own assertions.

```ml
    let helper index (x, y) =
      try
        expectedFunc x - tolerance <! y
        expectedFunc x + tolerance >! y
        ()
      with e ->
        // reraise
        // failwithf "exceed tolerance at index %i and values %f and %f" index x y
        XunitException("my message", e) |> raise
 
    actualAndCompareValues
    |> List.iteri helper
    |> ignore
```

if you explore the `Xunit.Sdk` namespace, you can discover many exception types you can use here. For instance if you Ctrl+Click on `Assert.True()` (decompile) it throws `Xunit.Sdk.TrueException`, which is inherited like this:

```
TrueException ->
 |_ AssertActualExpectedException
    |_ XunitException
      |_ Exception
```

Comment: Can I fail with a specific xUnit message? something like `Assert.Fail("Exceeded tolerance...")`

Comment: Could you explain how to do that? Googleing "custom xunit exception" did not yield anything I could use...

The best I figured out was to call `Assert.True(false, message)` where `message` is a string to be displayed with all the relevant info

Comment: added an explanation

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't muck around with trying to catch and rethrow the Xunit exception raised by the `<!` and `>!` Unquote operators. Instead, you could use `List.mapi` together with Unquote's `test` function to capture and raise richer expression messages at the source:

```
let isWithinToleranceOf expectedFunc tolerance actual =
    let helper index (x, y) =
        test <@ ignore index; expectedFunc x - tolerance < y @>
        test <@ ignore index; expectedFunc x + tolerance > y @>
            
    actual
    |> List.mapi helper
    |> ignore
```